# Efficient binary representation for Jackson TokenBuffer

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Is there an efficient way to serialize a Jackson `TokenBuffer` if I want to transfer it between two instances of my application?
Especially, I do not care about about the exact binary format that is used, but I do care about not repeatedly saving key strings. Consider, e.g. the following example:

```java
List msg = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  msg.add(new HashMap() {{
    put("asdfasdfasdf", i);
  }});
  // Doesn't necessarily have to be maps, could also be instances of some class
}
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
TokenBuffer tb = new TokenBuffer()
om.writeValue(tb, msg);
```

Now, if I just use some typical JsonGenerator to serialize the given `tb`,

```java
JsonParser p = tb.asParse();
p.nextToken();
OutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (JsonGenerator generator = (new CBORFactory()).createGenerator(bos)) {
  generator.copyCurrentStructure(p);
}
```

the String `asdfasdfasdf` will be contained 100 times in `bos`. Can I somehow avoid that? I.e. is there an instance of `JsonGenerator` for some binary format that supports duplicate map key elimination?

For comparison, had I done `(new Kryo()).writeClassAndObject(new Output(bos), msg)`, the string `asdfasdfasdf` would only be contained once in the binary output. But I already have the `tb` and no easy way to get back to `msg`, so I wonder how I could serialize and transfer `tb` in a time and size efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

A [`SmileFactory`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/smile) will do what I want, only inserting key strings once. However, I'm not convinced that it's the best option for my usecase. It seems to be possible to use an [auto-derived](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/avro#generating-avro-schema-from-pojo-definition) Avro schema together with the streaming API, resulting in much smaller serialized values, but for noticably increased CPU cost...